# Fix misspelled words on Android EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

How can I implement an EditText that automatically fixes misspelled words when taping soft keyboard spacebar? I have seen this behavior on Whatsapp, for example if you write "aricle" and press spacebar it puts "article", same if you write "articl" or something like that, is that an Android behavior or a Whatsapp specialized behavior? I have tried with AutoCompleteTextView and setting autoText=true (although is deprecated I had to try)

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: I'd say that it is a behaviour of the soft keyboard, not edittext

Answer (score 0):

Autocorrect is a feature of the keyboard that you use. But if you want to put this feature in your android application then you can use spelling checker framework offered by anroid. It lets you implement spelling checker in your android application with the help of android service. 
For more details you can see below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html#SpellCheckLifeCycle

And for example you can look into this link

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-androids-spelling-checker-framework--cms-23754